# Data of vehicle traffic

Tags: data-request, traffic

Does anyone know/have good dataset or data feed of vehicle traffic on freeways/highways or urban area?

I'm searching for data from vehicle counters that have small interval of measurement, like 1 or 5 minutes. Data should include vehicle count, average speed, types of vehicle, average headway or gap. Also it would be great if dataset or data feed has data about incidents like car accidents or roadworks and maybe time travel data from ANPR cameras.

Also there are lot of papers that talk about vehicle traffic prediction, but they don't give dataset they used for prediction and analysis. Maybe if you have datasets like that it would be great to share it with link to paper because I would like to reproduce results and try some other methods and compare performances.

Comment: see also this meta list of datasets: https://github.com/graphhopper/open-traffic-collection

Comment: it has been possible in the past to collect live data from the tomtom website. big ymmv. see my thread here: https://twitter.com/philshem/status/1241739025624567813

Answer (score 15):

You can find plenty of summary data, but I have not seen any publicly available raw counter data. Here's some summaries:

**Federal Highway Administration**
*Traffic Volume Trends is a monthly report based on hourly traffic count data reported by the States. These data are collected at approximately 4,000 continuous traffic counting locations nationwide and are used to estimate the percent change in traffic for the current month compared with the same month in the previous year.*

http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policyinformation/travel_monitoring/tvt.cfm

**Arizona Dept of Transportation**
*The annualized average 24-hour volume of vehicles at a given point or section of highway is called a traffic count. It is normally calculated by determining the volume of vehicles during a given period and dividing that number by the number of days in that period.*

http://www.azdot.gov/planning/DataandAnalysis

**California Dept. of Transportation**
*The Traffic Data Branch is responsible for the collection and dissemination of historical volumes (counts). We also produce the Mobility Performance Reports.
TRAFFIC COUNTS, also called Traffic Volumes, are available in various formats, and are only for the State Highway System. Highways are signed as Interstate, California State Route, or United States Route.*

http://traffic-counts.dot.ca.gov/

**Colorado Dept. of Transportation**
*This is the access point to information frequently used for transportation planning and project development. Information is provided on current and projected traffic volumes, state highway attributes, summary roadway statistics, demographics and geographic data.*

http://dtdapps.coloradodot.info/otis

**Florida Dept of Transportation**
*Welcome to the Florida Department of Transportation's Traffic Information site. This site provides statistical traffic information for Florida's State Highway System.*

http://www.dot.state.fl.us/planning/statistics/trafficdata/

**Indiana Dept of Transportation**
*INDOT Interactive Traffic Count Map showing the annual average daily traffic (AADT).*

http://dotmaps.indot.in.gov/apps/trafficcounts/

**Maine Dept of Transportation**
*Traffic Monitoring is responsible for the collection of all types of traffic data including traffic volumes, vehicle classification, turning movements and special studies as requested by the Department.  The reporting of traffic volumes is accomplished through two distinct methods involving the Continuous Count and Coverage (i.e. short term) Count programs.*

http://www.maine.gov/mdot/traffic/tc.htm

**Massachusetts Dept of Transportation**
*The Massachusetts Highway Department conducts an annual traffic data collection program. This data is available online by autoroute and city/town list or as an interactive map. You can view data for a specific town from the Town Index, for numbered routes from the Numbered Route Index, or you can use the interactive map to browse data by area. You can also download the complete spreadsheets*

http://www.mhd.state.ma.us/default.asp?pgid=content/traffic01&sid=about

**Michigan Dept of Transportation**
*2012 Average Daily Traffic (ADT) Maps*

https://www.michigan.gov/mdot/0,1607,7-151-9622_11033_11149---,00.html

**Minnesota Dept of Transportation**
*Thousands of traffic counts are collected on Minnesota roadways each year. This information is used to produce volume, classification, speed and weight data as well as traffic forecasts, reports, maps and analysis.*

http://www.dot.state.mn.us/traffic/data/

**New York State Dept of Transportation**
*The Highway Data Services Bureau is responsible for the collection and dissemination of information on the extent, use and condition of the public roadway system in the State of New York. The Bureau consists of three sections: Highway Data, Traffic Monitoring, and Pavement Data.*

https://www.dot.ny.gov/highway-data-services

**North Carolina Dept of Transportation**
*Annual Average Daily Traffic (AADT) Traffic Volume Map presents the traffic average for the year at specific points on North Carolina highways. Data is collected at more than 40,000 locations throughout North Carolina using Portable Traffic Count Stations. AADT map is typically published at the later part of the summer.*

http://www.ncdot.gov/projects/trafficsurvey/

**Ohio Dept of Transportation**
*Traffic Count Information & Maps includes Traffic Survey Reports and Traffic Survey Flow Maps. The Traffic Survey Reports list an estimate of Annual Average Daily Traffic (AADT) volumes separated by cars (Pass &A Com’l) and trucks (B&C Com’l) for all Ohio Interstate, US and State highway system routes.*

http://www.dot.state.oh.us/Divisions/Planning/TechServ/traffic/Pages/Traffic-Count-Reports-and-Maps.aspx

**Oregon Dept of Transportation**
*The Transportation Systems Monitoring (TSM) Unit has the mission to formulate a system to collect and process traffic related data on Oregon´s Highways. TSM provides traffic volumes, flow maps, trends, manual counts and vehicle class on state highways to Federal, State, Local, private and public constituents.*

http://www.oregon.gov/ODOT/td/tdata/Pages/tsm/tvt.aspx

**South Caroline Dept. of Transportation**
The Traffic Polling and Analysis System provides traffic data and graphs from traffic counting devices on South Carolina's Highways. This system is intended for the general public to view current and historical traffic information during hurricane evacuation events
**
http://www.scdot.org/getting/trafficcounts.aspx

**Tennessee Dept of Transportation**
*An AADT traffic volume is used throughout the project planning process to provide projected volumes of traffic.  It is based on a 24 hour, two directional count at a given location.  This raw traffic volume is then mathematically adjusted for vehicle type, determined by an axle correction factor.  Then this volume is statistically corrected by a seasonal variation factor that considers time of the year and day of the week.*

http://www.tdot.state.tn.us/projectplanning/adt.asp

**Washington State Dept of Transportation**
*The Annual Traffic Report (ATR) summarizes traffic data maintained by the Washington State Department of Transportation for the State Highway System. The report includes Annual Average Daily Traffic (AADT) figures and truck percentages, when available, for locations where data collection has occurred within the past four years.*

http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/mapsdata/travel/annualtrafficreport.htm

**Wisconsin Dept of Transportation**
*Wisconsin Department of Transportation (WisDOT) traffic counts are now part of an interactive map that allows you to view counts anywhere in the state.*

http://www.dot.wisconsin.gov/travel/counts/

**Chicago, IL Transportation**
Average Daily Traffic (ADT) counts are analogous to a census count of vehicles on city streets.
**

https://data.cityofchicago.org/Transportation/Average-Daily-Traffic-Counts/pfsx-4n4m

**Arlington, VA Transportation**
Arlington County Regular Traffic Count Data is available in Portable Document Format (PDF).
**

http://www.arlingtonva.us/Departments/EnvironmentalServices/dot/traffic/counts/EnvironmentalServicesCounts.aspx

**Delaware Valley, PA Delaware Valley Regional Planning Commission**
http://www.dvrpc.org/webmaps/trafficcounts/

**British Columbia, Canada Ministry of Transportation**
The Ministry of Transportation and Infrastructure's Traffic Data Program monitors *traffic volumes at several locations throughout the province. This information is used by ministry staff to help support planning, design, construction, and operation of the Ministry road network.*

http://www.th.gov.bc.ca/trafficData/

**United Kingdom (UK) Dept of Transportation**
*Traffic counts provides street-level traffic data for every junction-to-junction link on the 'A' road and motorway network in Great Britain.*

http://www.dft.gov.uk/traffic-counts/

**New South Wales, Australia Roads and Maritime**
*Traffic Volume Data books, sorted by Roads and Maritime Services regions, containing the Annual Average Daily Traffic (AADT) volumes for various roads.*

http://www.rms.nsw.gov.au/trafficinformation/downloads/aadtdata_dl1.html

Comment: Is there any one that contain hourly time series? Or even individualized vehicle data?

Comment: We have a collection here: https://github.com/graphhopper/open-traffic-collection I included your links (with reference) and also updated some of them

Answer (score 3):

California Performance measurement system (PEMS) has 5 minute and raw sensor data, as well as many levels of aggregation: http://pems.dot.ca.gov/

EDIT: Been looking through this and it's an awesome source. The raw data is every 30 seconds on every single freeway sensor in California which leads to 10's of millions of records every day. And you can download bulk records for the last 10 years (one day / one region at a time).

If you want to just take a peek without getting logon credentials I put some sample files here: http://www.stat.ucdavis.edu/~clarkf/

Answer (score 2):

There is a newly released dataset from ETH-Zürich

https://utd19.ethz.ch/

> The Institute for Transport Planning and Systems ETH Zurich collected the data in a research campaign from 2017-2019. The data mainly consists of measurements from loop detectors, which record vehicle flow and occupancy (or speed) in relatively small aggregation interval, typically 3-5min. The location of all detectors and the associated roads have been geo-coded in WGS84 coordinates making map matching as easy as possible. Its use is open to researchers from all over the world.

- 4.9 billion detected vehicles
- 40 cities
- 170 million data rows
- 23541 detectors
- 3-5 minute intervals
- 3.8 years of data
- Error-flagged
- Standardized dataset

obtaining the data request registration. publishing with the data requires attribution.

[image]