# Road traffic per national road in the Czech Republic

Tags: transportation, traffic

I'm looking for road traffic count/volume (i.e. number of cars) per road in the Czech Republic. Something like [this](http://www.ceskedalnice.cz/prilohy/intenzity-2005.jpg), although it should ideally be

- from recent years;
- a tabular dataset, not an image;
- per national road (not a must, e.g. per detector is fine as well);
- hourly data (yearly averages are also ok, if nothing else is available).

I searched for a while now, also on official channels like the [Czech Statistical Office](https://www.czso.cz/csu/czso/ministry-of-transport), but to no avail. The data should exist somewhere, since the National Traffic and Information Centre apparently measures volume of traffic. I don't know whether this data is published though and if so, where.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is Prague in this dataset? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/18028/1511. If not, check the other answers on that question. Or the tag [tag:traffic]

Comment: It isn't, unfortunately. Thanks for the link though. Also, I'm looking for data on the entire Czech Republic, not just Prague. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic didn't yield information on the traffic volume in CZ.